# Assigning variables in a function

Tags: python, variables, variable-assignment, local, local-variables

In the code below, I can see that the variables `end_line` and `internal_line` are assigned to their characters but then below that in the for loop, another variable called `end_line` is being assigned to the previous `end_line`. How?

```
def draw_grid(width, height):

    end_line = "+"
    
    internal_line = "|"
    
    for i in range(width):
        end_line = end_line + "-"
        internal_line = internal_line + " "
    end_line = end_line + "+"
    internal_line = internal_line + "|"
    
    print(end_line)
    
    for i in range(height):
        print(internal_line)
    
    print(end_line)

draw_grid(3,4)
```

The code works fine. I don't understand the variables or how they work.

Comment: It's not another variable, it's the same variable. It's adding another character to the variable.

Comment: So `end_line` starts as `+`, then it becomes `+-`, then `+--`, and so on.

Comment: You can replace the loop with `end_line = end_line + "-"*width`

Comment: Yes, that part i understand. I don't know how to articulate my question well enough. Maybe I should ask.. under the for loop when it says:
end_line = end_line + "-"  ..... is it reading "+" = "+" + "-" (hahaha lord help me)

Comment: The expression `end_line + "-"` means to concatenate the current value of `end_line` and the string `-`. This result is then stored back into `end_line`. So if `end_line` is currently `+`, it becomes `+-`. The next time, the current value is `+-`, so it becomes `+--`.

Comment: Oh okay so because it's in a for loop it updates the value?

Comment: It doesn't have to be in a for loop. See the line `end_line = end_line + "+"` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Actually python being a really high level programming language, automates the process of concatenating strings.
In C for example you would have to call a function like strcat(string1, string2) and this function would create a new variable containing both strings and saving heap memory for the size of string1 + string2.
Python saves this process and all is resizes to just use '+' symbol between two strings.
In conclusion:
end_line = end_line + "-"
is translated as:
end_line = "+-"

You can see more information here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_concatenation.asp